# ggboxplot significance bracket position too high

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `ggpubr` libray. For some reason, the locations of the brackets are too high. Is there any way to put them a little lower. I don't want to position each one by one.

```
library(ggpubr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    Value = c(rnorm(50),rnorm(50)+10,rnorm(50)+20),
    Group = sample(1:4, 150, replace = T),
    Class = rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=50),
    M = sample(LETTERS[25:26], 150, replace = T))

df %>% ggboxplot(x = "Group", y = "Value",
                 facet.by = c("Class", "M"), scales="free_y") + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("1", "2"), c("2","3"),c("1","4")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way...just export the plot as pdf with a much higher hegiht, you can also do this by `pdf(height = ...)`

[image]

then you got:

[image]

Comment: This helps for visualization, but not really for publication.